# Getting response body of mock service worker

Tags: javascript, mocking, msw

I am trying to use mock service worker to intercept a response from an endpoint and then modify one field of that json response. If we have an endpoint `/user` that returns a json looking like

```
users: [{
  user: {
    name: John,
    age: 31,
    occupation: Engineer
  }
}]
```

I would like to be able to intercept the response from within msw post and change the occupation to be "Student"

So, I believe my handler should return something where it manipulates `res`?

```
rest.post('*/users', (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res((res) => {
    ????
  }
}
```

This general idea wouldn't work because the response mocked response body is Null?

Comment: If you're mocking out you're not _hitting_ the real endpoint (which is the point, then your tests can run much faster). Why not just respond with exactly what you want?

Comment: @jonrsharpe for a couple of reasons: first off, I want the rest of the information that the endpoint provides (i.e. I want age and name from the endpoint but I want to be able to manipulate occupation). Also, this response is directly used in another script, so I cannot just manipulate the response directly

Answer (score 1):

[Response Patching](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/response-patching) probably allows what I think you're describing.

You can write something like the following:

```
rest.post('*/users', async (req, res, ctx) => {
    const originalResponse = await ctx.fetch(req)
    const originalResponseData = await originalResponse.json() 
    // if you like TypeScript you can add to the previous line
    // as {name: string, age: number, occupation: string}
    // or use a defined type.

    return res(
      ctx.json({
        ...originalResponseData,
        occupation: 'Student',
      }),
    )
})
```

or since your post actually had arrays, maybe:

```
rest.post('*/users', async (req, res, ctx) => {
    const originalResponse = await ctx.fetch(req)
    const originalResponseData = await originalResponse.json() as {occupation: string, name: string, age: number}[]

    // Make all returned users Students, or whatever you need here...
    const modifiedResponse = originalResponseData.map((user) => {
        return {
            ...user,
            occupation: 'Student'
        }
    })
    return res(ctx.json(modifiedResponse))
}),
```

Comment: If you need to fetch the actual data (not mocked), response patching is the way to go. This looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Conditional response](https://mswjs.io/docs/basics/response-resolver#conditional-response) and [Include failure scenarios](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/request-assertions#include-failure-scenarios) of MSW.

The mock response depends on the request. We can return different mock responses based on request url parameters. We can add a `testcase` url parameter to the endpoint of the mock handler, use this control the handler returns the different mock responses.

E.g.

```js
rest.post('*/users', (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(
    ctx.json({
      users: [
        {
          user: {
            name: 'John',
            age: 31,
            occupation: req.url.searchParams.get('testcase') === 'student' ? 'Student' : 'Engineer',
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  );
});
```